# Does exists a way to accelerate the load of jquery & jqueryui?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Im a fan of jquery & jqueryui, but some friends still arguing me than the pages gets too heavy and slow because my use of jquery & jqueryui. I was sure that the difference is not more than 10% (acceptable for me).

But, a php&mysql progam, listing a single 100 records table without format (a html table) runs 50% faster than the same program with jquery & jqueryui. (mostly loading the files). Even when they are in cache the first one runs *way* faster than the second one.

Im thinking in join all the files in a single one... it doesnt look easy to maintain, but I bet it will be faster. (finally, a compiled program put all the stuff together, so it doesnt sound crazy).

a) Does exists a program that automate joins all the include stuff (js, css, php, html) in one single file for each page?

b) Is there a smarter way to accelerate the loading time for jquery, jqueryui & css files?

TIA,

Comment: If the files are cached and you are loading from cache, then the difference should be single digit milliseconds in loading.

Comment: a dozen+ sites will test your sites speed and make recommendations

Comment: `Even when they are in cache the first one runs way faster than the second one` - so, loading times of those libraries isn't due to `(mostly loading the files)` as you claim. We recently changed all uses of `jQuery.each` on arrays to use array native forEach method (with polyfill for older internet explorer) - that one change has made a significant improvement to our website perceived responsiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great post on this [here](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax)

Make sure you are using minified `.css` and `.js` files.

Only include the components of jQuery UI that you actually use.

Consider using a HTTP cache such as Varnish to cache static content.

Consider using some form of CDN. Cloudflare can minify HTML. Alternatively, if you have control of your HTTP server you could add a plugin [such as this one for Nginx](https://github.com/nginx-modules/nginx-minify) to minify all content.

Beyond this, there aren't many options beyond making sure your queries and code are as simplistic and efficient as possible.

Comment: Thank you! Im not allowed to put publicly an useful check (But I did it). BTW, Great post,

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped :)